# Moving a bone, makes another bones but further

Tags: bones

Is there a way i make a bone controls another bone's movement?
To be specific, when i move Bone A up to 50cm, it also move Bone B which also move twice further?
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Transformation** constraint or you can use a **driver**.

*Transformation* constraint:

Give it to your bone in *Pose* mode. Don't forget to select *Local Space* and to activate *Extrapolate*, in the *Map To* part, choose a value that will be twice the one of the *Map From*:

[image]

Now when you move the target bone:

[image]

Drivers solution:

Right click on the Y value of the bone and choose *Add Driver*:

[image]

Open the *Drivers* editor, select the *Y Location Bone* track on the left and in the *N panel > Drivers* choose the controller bone as *Object, Type > Y Location, Space > Local Space*, and under *Expression* type "var*2":

[image]